# Check if a website has Open Graph Protocol

Tags: web, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

If I paste a website to Skype, for example, a thumbnail previewing the page will exist, because it has an open graph protocol set up.

Assuming I have a big list of websites, and I'm trying to determine the one that has OGP and will preview, how would I do it? If I paste them all onto skype and one of them works, it'll preview properly, but the problem is Skype's message limit, which would make the process very slow if the list is large.

Basically, out of a long list, I'd like to have a fast way to check which website out of all of them would preview. On discord and facebook the same thing applies, but there's a similar message limit. Unfortunately emailing myself the list doesn't generate the preview.

I know it's an unorthodox question but I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. The only way to do this is to download the HTML code of the website and look in the `<head>` for any `<meta>` elements.

You could then search for [`property="og:image"`](http://ogp.me/) to see if there is an image associated with the page.

If you don't want to download the full page, you could use the [HTTP Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) request and just grab the first couple of KB of the page.

How you do that will depend on the programming language you use.